# React Storybook throws error when using npx sb init

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook, npx

I am trying to install Storybook on my project. All I do is initialize the create-react-app and then cd to the current directory. When I enter 'npx sb init' I am getting the following errors:

```
 • Detecting project type. ✓
 • Adding Storybook support to your "Create React App" based project
     Unable to find versions of @storybook/react using npm

     Unable to find versions of @storybook/addon-links using npm

     Unable to find versions of @storybook/addon-essentials using npm

     Unable to find versions of @storybook/addon-actions using npm

     Unable to find versions of @storybook/node-logger using npm

     Unable to find versions of @storybook/preset-create-react-app using npm
```

System
Node: v16.13.0
NPM: 8.1.4
Ubuntu 21.10

Notes
I was able to find a relatable problem [here](https://issuehunt.io/r/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14688), but unfortunately it doesn't seem logical to init the project on a VM and then copy it locally..

Comment: what command do you use to install?

Comment: I use npx create-react-app test > cd test > npx sb init

Comment: did you try to uninstall the global installed CRA and cleaning the cache?

Comment: yes, the problem still persists..

Comment: can you try once without npx?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
I had the same issue. The problem was that I had installed node through snap. https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md - here is the example how to install on Debian / Ubuntu without using snap.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR - I had the same issue, with a snap installed node on a system with i3wm and fish, and a project with ReactJS and next.js. I used fnm to install node as recommended by nodejs.org and reinstall of storybook was successful. (It was not necessary to make any installation changes to CRA)

My setup is i3wm and fish, so I could not use nvm (no native support for fish at time of writing, though numerous posts to describe how to work around)

nodejs.org recommends fnm, which I installed (see [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions))

then:

```
>fnm list-remote | tail
v20.8.1
v20.9.0 (Iron)
v20.10.0 (Iron)
v20.11.0 (Iron)
v21.0.0
v21.1.0
v21.2.0
v21.3.0
v21.4.0
v21.5.0  
> fnm install 21.5.0
 Installing Node v21.5.0 (x64)
> fnm list
* v21.5.0 default
* system
> fnm use 21.5.0
Using Node v21.5.0
fnm list
* v21.5.0 default
* system
```

The install of storybook was per website [instructions](https://storybook.js.org/docs/get-started/install):

```
> npx storybook@latest init
```